# Find and Comparison in Dos script ?

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, find

I run a third party command that displays error levels like this after it executes:

```
 return code: 33
 return code: 1
 return code: 4
 return code: 5
```

I pipe the result of the command into a log file. So test.log will have any combination 
of these lines for examples:

```
 return code: 33
 return code: 1
```

In my script I want to check the content of the log file and if the entry code was anything
but 1  ( one means success ) I will do an action

I think the find command is what I have to use but not sure what syntax to use? 
Basically the logic should be, look into log file and if the error code is anything but 1 do some action.

Can anyone suggest how to write a code to check this?

Thanking you in advance
Matt

Comment: You only want to check the last line in the log file, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a file test.log containing:

```
return code: 33
return code: 1
return code: 4
return code: 5
```

Your batch script to analyze test.log would look something like this:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /e /v ": 1" test.log') do (
    echo %%i
    rem do some other command instead of echo
)
```

[Findstr](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx)'s /e switch match pattern at the end of the line and /v switch chooses everything except the match. The result will be:

```
return code: 33
return code: 4
return code: 5
```

**EDIT below**

If content of text is something like below and we also want to do something with text `alternate: 1`,

```
return code: 33
return code: 1
return code: 4
return code: 5
alternate: 1
```

We would make a subtle change like so:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /e /v "return code: 1" test.log') do (
    echo %%i
    rem do some other command instead of echo
)
```

This way we extract everything but `return code: 1`.

**EDIT 2**

To exit out of the loop after the first instance, do this:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /e /v "return code: 1" test.txt') do (
    echo %%i
    goto :eof
)
:eof
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply - however the log file may contain other instance of 1 .. The content of the log file is not limited to return code only - so I'm sorry I forgot to mention that. What is there was another : 1 in the log file that had nothing to do with the return code? Then this would not work? Can you please elaborate on your solution please?

Comment: Hi @mattbeyond, good point. If you had another: 1, the code I originally posted will not work. I have added an edit so that you get everything except `return code: 1`. Hope that will help you.

Comment: Hi thanks again!!! Greatly apperciate this ..  - This works great ,,But somehow I get into an endless loop .. How do I exit this after the first occurance happens? For whatever reason I get into a loop. In my script I want to say ,, So the logic should be .. as soon as you find the occurance do this and then exit

Comment: Sorry - I just want to read the entire file and if there is any instance of the text occur theh do some action. When I run your code .. if there are three instance of the text it echos it three times. and it loops. This is so easy in Linux Shell

Comment: Hi @mattbeyond, I have added a dreadful `goto` that might do the trick. You were probably wanting something like `grep <something> <file> | head -1 ...xarg...` etc. You code that very well with PowerShell; I'll have to look up commands and I certainly can if you would like.

Comment: Ok - first of all thanks for your patience !! I figured out what the issue is - but I have no solution for it -I used ur code and it works as is in a script. However when I plug it into my script and pass the file name to check as a variable it fails.   This is what happens : instead of test.txt I put %12345.txt% . for whatever reason the find command looks at the file name 12345.txt and searches the string there. It does not look at the content of the file. Since i have date and numbers in the name of the file, it always gives the same result

Comment: Hi @mattbeyond, if your file has `%` sign, you would have to escape it with `%%`. Try to pass on the file in double quotes and receive in double quotes as well like so: `findstr /e /v "return code: 1" "%1"`. Let me know if this helps, or does not help.

Comment: thanks again - the problem is %%! .. I need to set it to nothing before I use it in your code. How cab I set %%i to nothing. It picks up the value from my previous function?

Comment: the %%i is used in another function so when I call it again in your code it contain a value from the previous function .. that's why is not working

Comment: I see you have posted another question. Let me ask questions there so we can look at your detailed code there as well

Comment: I tried "" by the way - but that did not help. Is there a way to reset the delims=" %%i ? set the value of it to zero before I begin

Comment: yes - just getting really frustrated.. I see the value being passed on from one function to the next .. it has nothing to do with ur code . it works fine outside of  my script

Comment: Hang in there, you are doing a great job of debugging. You'll find the solution

Comment: Thank u so much!! Can we post on the other question and close this one?

Comment: closing this discussion as ur code works on its own - but not within my script

Answer (score 1):

The following will determine if there exists at least one return code in the log file that is not 1:

```
findstr /rxc:"return code: [0-9]*" test.log | findstr /ev ": 1" >nul && echo Do something
```

The following loop allows you to take action on each non 1 return code:

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %%A in (
  'findstr /rxc:"return code: [0-9]*" test.log ^| findstr /ev ": 1"'
) do (
  echo return code = %%A
  echo So do something about it
)
```

If it is not matching because of extra spaces, try:

```
findstr /rxc:" *return code: *[0-9]* *" test.log | findstr /ev ": 1" >nul && echo Do something
```

Comment: This is so easy in Unix - Having a hell of time . I just want to read the entire log file ( I do not want to read it in a loop )

Comment: tstxtract return code: 33
tstxtract return code: 2
tstxtract return code: 0

Comment: Hi Sorry - the code works but the output is not what I'm looking for  I get three rows of output tstxtract return code: 33
tstxtract return code: 2
tstxtract return code: 0

Comment: Basically I want to take action as soon as it find the first instance - This looks like it shows all the instances .. It looks like a loop

Comment: Sorry - about above comments - it was measn for the other solution -You code is not finding anything - it is not working - the echo never is a sucess -

Comment: @mattbeyond - The first one liner worked for me, and the simple batch script was missing a percent (fixed now). My search might have different spacing than your log. I added another 1 liner that should work regardless how many spaces are at beginning or end of line, or after the colon.

Comment: @mattbeyond - I'm not sure where you are going wrong. I tested with the sample data you provided, and is sure works for me. I also tested with extra lines added, as well as extra spaces, and it works.

Comment: I tried it several time .. When I get a chance I come back and have a go at it again, Thanks for your help and patienec